# Replace value of id in URL

Tags: javascript, html, string, function, url

I have URLs of that form:

> https://www.merkel.com/obama?trump=15&id=9616071454&hilarry=es

I would like, via [javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript) to replace 9616071454 with 1, for example.

I know about the [replace()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_replace.asp), but this will replace "id" itself, *not* the value of "id".

Is there anything common in the web dev world? :)

Comment: `str.replace(/\bid=\d+/, 'id=1')`

Comment: I will check @AvinashRaj, but [can you please explain a bit](https://xkcd.com/1171/)? :)

Comment: You should know better than this in terms of [ask].

Comment: @Amit the only attempt I had was with `replace()`, you mean to include that in my question? Avinash, it works, thanks! Thanks Titus!

Comment: @gsamaras `\b` matches between a word char and not word char or (vice-versa). `\d+` matches one or more digit chracters . So the above regex would match the whole id paramater along with it's value.

Comment: @gsamaras then post the actual url.

Comment: This will also work `url.replace(/(&?id=)(\d+)/, "$1"+id);` Where `url` is the link and `id` is the new id.

Comment: could `id` param be presented with not only digits and some other characters?

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest in my specific scenario no, but if you would like to post an *answer* taking care of this too, it would be nice for future users! :)

Comment: @gsamaras, added some extended case

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution considering situations when:

- `id` param can contain other characters besides digits
- avoiding fragment `#` replacement when `id` is followed by `#`

---

```
var str = 'https://www.foo.com/bar?trump=15&hilarry=es&id=961607some1454text#fragment',
    newId = 1,
    replaced = str.replace(/\bid=[^&#]+/g, "id=" + newId);

console.log(replaced); // "https://www.foo.com/bar?trump=15&hilarry=es&id=1#fragment"
```

Answer (score 2):

Simply hard-code that `&id=` to be re-replaced.

```js
var str = 'https://www.merkel.com/obama?trump=15&id=9616071454&hilarry=es';
var str2 = 'https://www.merkel.com/obama?id=9616071454&trump=15&hilarry=es';
var newId = '123';

str = str.replace(/([&?])id=[0-9]+/, '$1id=' + newId);
str2 = str2.replace(/([&?])id=[0-9]+/, '$1id=' + newId);

alert(str);
alert(str2);
```

Comment: what if the id exists at the start? `\b` would cover all the cases.

Answer (score 1):

Its simple pattern matching. You can refer to this [URL](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_regexp.asp) about pattern matching.

```
function(newValue,url) {
   url=url.replace(/id=\d+/,'id='+newValue);
   return url;
}
```

Comment: Nice attempt. Make sure you check the top comment under my question! ;) +1

Answer (score 0):

This function works and it allows you to pick way parameter you want.

```
var exampleStrng ='trump=15&id=9616071454&hilarry=es'; // this is an example query string.
   var urlQry = window.document.location.search.substring(1); // you can use this in live code to get the query string.

// reusable function for split in text.
function strSpliter( str, splitVal ){
   return str.split(splitVal);
}

 // function to reassign query parameter values.
function changQry(qry, setParam, chngVal){
var pnt = strSpliter(qry, '&'),//use the spliter function to change the query into an array split on the '&' character.
newQryArr = [],  // a temp array to hold the new parameters and their value.
newQry = '',// this will be the string where the query parameters and values are reconstructed into a string.
newQryStr = '';// this will be the query with the new value.

pnt.forEach( function( item, idx ){
var param = strSpliter(item, '=');  //use the spliter function to split the parameter and their value.

 // checks the parameter against the one you want to change.
if( param[0] === setParam ){
   param[1] = chngVal;// assigns the new value to the parameter. 

   newQryArr.push(param.join('=')); // rejoins the parameter and its value and pushes it into the temp array.
} else {
   newQryArr.push(param.join('='));// rejoins the parameter and its value and pushes it into the temp array.
}

newQry = newQryArr.join('&');// rejoins all the parameters and their values.
newQryStr = '?' + newQry;// creates the new query string.

});
 return newQryStr; // returns the new search query string.

}

  changQry(exampleStrng, 'id', 77777745);
```

### without comments

var urlQry = window.document.location.search.substring(1);

```
function strSpliter( str, splitVal ){
   return str.split(splitVal);
}

function changQry(qry, setParam, chngVal){
    var pnt = strSpliter(qry, '&'),
           newQryArr = [],
           newQry = '',
           newQryStr = '';

pnt.forEach( function( item, idx ){
   var param = strSpliter(item, '=');

   if( param[0] === setParam ){
      param[1] = chngVal;
      newQryArr.push(param.join('='));
   } else {
      newQryArr.push(param.join('='));
   }

   newQry = newQryArr.join('&');
   newQryStr = '?' + newQry;
});
   return newQryStr;
}

  changQry(urlQry, 'id', 77777745);
```

Comment: Too dense...Maybe I will read it when I have some time andre, thank you! :)